# Python:List.append() at all indexes instead of the desired index

Tags: python

File:
0 1\n2 1\n0 2\n1 3

The above is the to-be imported file,and I want the result to be an adjacency list. However the outcome is [[1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1], [1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1], [1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1], [1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1]] instead of [[1,2],[0,2,3],[1,0],[1]]. I think the problem comes from this line:

```
    adjList[i].append(g[0])
```

but I can't find what's wrong with it

Code:

```
    n = int(input('Enter the value for n: '))
    filename = input('Enter the file name: ')
    t = open(filename,'r+')

    adjList = [[]]*n
    c = t.read().split('\n')


    for i in range(n):
        for j in c:
            if str(i) in j:
                g = [int(k) for k in j.split(' ') if k != str(i)]
                adjList[i].append(g[0])


    print(adjList)
    t.close()
```

Comment: This answers my question! Thank you so much!

Comment: Duplicate question